# Rotating OpenGL-ES object

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2, opengl-es-2.0

After many hours of struggle i was finally able to draw a object, but got stuck when it came to rotating. I am trying to make a rotation around the y-axis, but i cannot seem to make the rotation smooth in any way. Its pretty much jumping around. There might be some bits and pieces of uneccessary in between hence i used a template.

```
- (void)update
{
    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, startPoint.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    dx = dy = 0;
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    _normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(modelViewMatrix), NULL);

    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.5f;
}
```

And my touch behaviours:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    dx = point.y - startPoint.y;
    dy = point.x - startPoint.x;
    startPoint = point;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

going through the below link of apple library it can be solve your problem
  [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLSprite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007325

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the sample does not have any user interaction in means of touch.